# Authorization NOT applied to DELETE actions

Tags: cakephp, authorization, middleware

When I **delete** an entity, cakephp warns that the request did not apply authorization checks. When I go back to previous action, the **entity is deleted**. Somehow it happens by bypassing the **authorization** middleware. 
**PS**
I'm using a skeleton app from composer. I have not applied authorization to the delete action. I expected the delete to fail but it persists.

CakePHP 4

Controller code.

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $product = $this->Products->get($id);

    if ($this->Products->delete($product)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been deleted.'));


    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);


}
```

Comment: Please share the code of your controller.

Comment: @AmanRawat added controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't bypassing authorization, it simply doesn't apply any authorization checks.

Authorization doesn't happen automatically, unless you explicitly configure/setup something that automatically issues checks, like for example the [**request authorization middleware**](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/request-authorization-middleware.html), or [**model and action based authorization**](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/component.html#automatic-authorization-checks). If you don't have something like that configured, you have to [**issue authorization checks manually**](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/checking-authorization.html) where required.

The message that no checks have been applied is primarily a debugging aid, the check happens in the middleware *after* your controller code already ran (it's not really possible to check it earlier, as your code is free to apply authorization checks at pretty much any point in your code).

If you explicitly want an action to *not* require authorization, then you can notify the component about it, by calling its `skipAuthorization()` method:

```php
$this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
```

See also

- **[Authorization Cookbook > Checking Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/checking-authorization.html)**
- **[Authorization Cookbook > AuthorizationComponent > Automatic authorization checks](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/component.html#automatic-authorization-checks)**
- **[Authorization Cookbook > AuthorizationComponent > Skipping Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/component.html#skipping-authorization)**